# SQL Integer Division Remainder

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my situation: Say I have 7 hats.

```
Month       Hats
1           7
```

In my select statement I need to divide this by 3 and I can't have partial hats . I want to have 3 records with the following values:

```
Week     Hats
1        2
2        2
3        3
```

With normal rounding I would end up

```
Week     Hats
1        2
2        2
3        2
```

I cant have this cause i just lost a hat. How do I give the remainder of the quotient to one record (I don't care what record)?

Comment: Divide by number of weeks (int division) and then add the modulo to the last/desired week (#hats % #weeks). SQL Server 2005+ only.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929751/divide-amount-equally-in-sql-server/20929917#20929917) is a similar question. The solution was to keep subtracting whilst tracking the remainder.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I think its SQL Server 10.5

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.  You can do this using SQL-only.  The idea is to allocate the number of hats as an integer.  Then, add an additional hat to each week until you hit the total needed.

Here is a query that accomplishes this, for the data you have proposed:

```
with weeks as (
      select 1 as w union all select 2 union all select 3
     ),
     const as (
      select 7 as numhats,
             (select count(*) from weeks) as numweeks
     )
select w,
       ((numhats / numweeks) +
        (case when row_number() over (order by w) <= numhats % numweeks
              then 1
              else 0
         end)
       ) as hats
from weeks cross join
     const;
```

Note that this puts the extra hats on the first weeks rather than the last weeks.  You could put them on the last weeks by using `order by w desc` instead of `order by w`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to you need some additional information. Track the original total, and find the sum of what was allocated

```
Week      HatNum     HatColor     OrigTotal     SumWeekHats     RowID
1         2          Blue         7             6               1
2         2          Blue         7             6               2
3         2          Blue         7             6               3
1         2          Red          7             6               1
2         2          Red          7             6               2
3         2          Red          7             6               3
```

Then update the hatNum (for 1 row per group) based on what hasn't been allocated